# Apple Authentication and GDPR Contradiction

Tags: javascript, swift, react-native, apple-sign-in

I am trying to understand what Apple is imposing as its new policy to ask developers to use Apple's own authentication mechanism.

Apparently Apple is using a different method compared to other authorization providers, such as Facebook and Google.

Apple's approach is, you receive the name and email at first login (say sign in). And after that you only receive a user id (something like `001134.432857YEASUREe274bxy231b3.0884` which means nothing unless you save it along with email and user name at the sign up).

Up to now everything seems fine.

The part that makes me confused starts here.

According to GDPR, as far as I know, you have to provide users a right to delete all their data from your servers.

And in this case, once we delete a user's all data then the correlation between "email+fullname vs user id" is lost for ever.

If the same user decides to reactivate herself, this time Apple will not send you email+fullname and this will impact the user experience.

Is my understanding correct? What is the solution for this problem?

References:

1. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple
2. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/verifying_a_user
3. https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/apple-authentication/

Comment: how about hashing email+fullname for that purpose? I don't know a lot about gdpr but I found this answer: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/29755/is-hash-of-a-username-still-personal-data

Comment: Actually that is a very good idea, thanks. But as far as I understood from the link apples scenario falls into “pseudonymisation” if we keep the apples provided id. Apple will provide only rejoining user’s id and keeping it hashed is not full anonymity (as far as I understood).